# Tweaking py-shiny layout

Tags: javascript, python, css, r, py-shiny

I created a [minimal example](https://shinylive.io/py/editor/#code=NobwRAdghgtgpmAXGKAHVA6VBPMAaMAYwHsIAXOcpMAMwCdiYACAZwAsBLCbJjmVYnTJMAgujxM6lACZw6EgK4cAOhHqMmqKBGlQWvfoOEARKGSgAxOrDirVNYsSYBeJqfNWbAClVM-TYF9-YJAg4PCmZTARKMRIsABZHlQOQjIFKSi8MIj-KIBJGCgAc1skJgByAB4+YqYoABthQga9Fmco1AZpBTSAWj4SstY6Qg6wNjIyVBZEAHo5lnMyVIBGDBIGho5ZOkHSlg3GOYB3QWkuuBYWU9Q+knJKMjmFVAbiKGkbgCYABm-vnNfgAWOZkNhwPpFFgAaz6ACs+PcoHQpNg+jQ4GYMnAMPDUMUokwIRxipNnMCAKxRAB8FWyEFyTAAvjkALqqACUdmg6AA+koXEwlFghnyaA0lNIfIz-CKtBA4A0+SsyA04D4wBZHKJoA1sCwOCwopyGcERa1sMQFGQ+YbZAAjFEypny7RKu07OBOuguplyjiixXKk5Khp+-3hEVcVA2u1KuBpDgALw1OUjESihDMcGKgmwWXiAGEc3m6NhEIXCGxiKkrs5gKsJN8JABmNkSFgJtJwaQNptMFtMdvAX4c2UZ-zcif+03p3InHbg5yts25Ocz82BhUeopcCP+kXW6Zx3TmcXWeCaqQsBRNE1riIb4Ib6c82Q0VhyABuci8MZtCRj1jMhOyuQ1SE5SsZwAAWAm0chgqQdDkDAzygC8bByD9JCuO8yC8KD5z8KR0joRlkN2DB3CgABxPZpQcYg3wgVQ0FQIUxFQLx2IFDgwLoX86GnMBmTZIA) (directly editable online). I have few very small questions how to tweak it to look better.

1. First of all, how to set the height to 100%? The problem is the the "category" selectize which goes "inside" of the outer box.
   [image]
2. How to get rid of these borders around the outer box. What helped on one page was `ui.tags.style(ui.HTML(".bslib-sidebar-layout .sidebar { border: 0px; }")),`

[image]

3. Since I follow the same structure of the page on every page - how can I set both 1 and 2 globally?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's a very straight forward once you know the targeted CSS class name, you could use [Global Styling](https://shiny.posit.co/py/docs/ui-styling.html#global-styling).

Here's an example where I apply global styling to the `ui.page_fluid` shiny component, where everything is placed in the shiny app:

- [Global Styling Example](https://shinylive.io/py/editor/#code=NobwRAdghgtgpmAXGKAHVA6VBPMAaMAYwHsIAXOcpMAMwCdiYACAZwAsBLCbJjmVYnTJMAgujxM6lACZw6EgK4cAOhHqMmqKBGlQWvfoOEARKGSgAxOrDirVNYsSYBeJqfNWbAClVM-TYF9-YJAg4PCmZTARKMRIsABZHlQOQjIFKSi8MIj-KIBJGCgAc1skJgByAB4+YqYoABthQga9Fmco1AZpBTSAWj4SstY6Qg6wNjIyVBZEAHo5lnMyVIBGDBIGho5ZOkHSlg3GOYB3QWkuuBYWU9Q+knJKMjmFVAbiKGkbgCYABm-vnNfgAWOZkNhwPpFFgAaz6ACs+PcoHQpNg+jQ4GYMnAMPDUMUokwIRxipNnMCAKxRAB8FWyEFyTAAvjkALqqACUdmg6AA+koXEwlFghnyaA0lNIfIz-CLzMVDktsA04DKmVFNWAcsEMAAjFjbPV9Fg7OB6lF9VrYYgKYShWVMvx685yOK-VAADwA3Drcn0+gajSatIQ3UxflIYL7HU6SWSyIhVr9fgBSP0RVmx4JazWxzkM4IirQQOANPkrMiqnxgCyOUTQBrYU0sKIFnIi622sh802yC10dW5YvaMu9s0DodO4UcUWl8snMsNKfTuWzrioO29stwNIcABeaozq78UUIZjgxUE2Cyx5PUQAwher3RsIhb9mT-5CGxiKkrs4wCrBI3wSAAzGyhZfhELA7mkcDSIBwFMKBTAQcAvyQXeuTcp+ETtnh4QnDs4LOGBUH4RR4QjvOfJFFwK5MiK3abj2ujmOK1jwDWUgsAoTRtlRwQEcJDK4Tysg0KwcgAG5yF4G52hILFKdJ1wcKQnLvrGAACKlkDkOlSDocgYOxUCcTYOSSZIVz8WQXhaceUjpHQjLGbsGDuFAADiezSg4xDiRAqhoKgQpiKgXhhQKHASLBdByXQuFgMybJAA)

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It helps. How would you implement it, if you have pages like `/foo` and `/boo`. 

How would you apply it "globally" in this case? Repeating the code?

Comment: @abe I would use tabs to implement different pages without the need of creating routes for every page, but it depends on the app use case and its complexity. In terms of styling, I'd use a separate CSS file like [here](https://shiny.posit.co/py/docs/ui-styling.html#using-an-external-css-file), for flexibility, reusability and applying best practice regarding project structure.

Comment: yes! this solved the issue! thanks! i do have to use the routing. do you have accidently an idea how to create a side bar? The framework offers here a sidebar (https://shiny.posit.co/py/api/ExSidebar.html) but how to i fill it with pages and navigation?

Comment: I am targeting at smth like this https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/ (but there is python packages for this - at least I could not find it)

Comment: @abe You can definitely achieve similar results using bootstrap classes like [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sidebars/#) if you put some effort into it. I can't share it here due to characters limits, but you can begin with [nav_list](https://shiny.posit.co/py/docs/ui-navigation.html#lists) in shiny to display the content based on the sidebar choice.

Comment: that would be really great. I have created a ticket, could you please make an example. I think that would be useful for many py-shiny beginners (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77195758/py-shiny-example-of-sidebar-similar-to-dashboards-in-r)

Comment: @abe you know what would be better, asking this to the shiny team themselves as they are developing the framework, we have a community in discord https://discord.gg/rtzZzPeC
feel free to join us and asks any question you have.

Comment: Ah wow! did not know that! Thanks! I will join otherwise I will spam the stackoverflow